# Different SHA-256 hashes depending on whether input is measured with sizeof or strlen

Tags: c, string, hash

I'm writing a program that computes the SHA-256 of a string read from `stdin`. 
I'm using the functions provided by `openssl/sha.h` into my program. I implemented a "normal hash" and a "salted hash".

**Normal hash**

If I hash the word `password` I get the following outputs:

```
SHA256_Update(&sha256, string, strlen(string)) --> 5e884898da28047151d0e56f8dc6292773603d0d6aabbdd62a11ef721d1542d8
SHA256_Update(&sha256, string, sizeof(string)) --> 5e884898da28047151d0e56f8dc6292773603d0d6aabbdd62a11ef721d1542d8
```

which are correct, as seen by the output of the shell command

```
echo -n "password" | sha256sum --> 5e884898da28047151d0e56f8dc6292773603d0d6aabbdd62a11ef721d1542d8
```

**Salted hash**

Then I tried to implement a *salted hash*, concatenating the input string after another string (the salt), obtaining

```
complete = salt + string
```

Given that the salt is always the same (`26000`, computed as 13*2000), I expected output matching the shell command:

```
echo -n "26000password" | sha256sum --> c9bcf6ab867bdff7bf2223407c6a391f5c475fb411f7eae08fb361a671d4fd0d
```

Using `strlen(complete)` gives me the correct answer:

```
SHA256_Update(&sha256, complete, strlen(complete)) --> c9bcf6ab867bdff7bf2223407c6a391f5c475fb411f7eae08fb361a671d4fd0d
```

However, using `sizeof(complete)` gives me a different answer:

```
SHA256_Update(&sha256, complete, sizeof(complete)) --> ef73eaf729a0601f9d99ed0a11ef82ae82ca74042de5a724889f82e4f6e59bb0
```

So I have two problems:

1. The second case has something wrong (I presume is the use of `sizeof` instead of `strlen`, but that doesn't explain why I got the second problem, so I'm thinking about some "inconsistent state of the memory");
2. If I execute the program again, the wrong hash keeps changing every time I stop and execute the program.

So I assume that the problem is in the use of `sizeof` instead of `strlen`. I know that `sizeof` returns the number of bytes used to store that data type (so a pointer will be 4 bytes), while `strlen` will give me the length of the string, but I don't understand why I got the errors only in the second case.

**Code excerpts**

```
#include <openssl/sha.h>
#define MAX_LENGTH 1024

unsigned long salt;

// Salted ////////////////////////////////
void compute_sha256_with_sizeof_complete(const char *string, char *sha)
{
    int i;
    char temp[65];
    char complete[MAX_LENGTH];
    char salt_str[MAX_LENGTH];
    unsigned char hash[SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH];  
    SHA256_CTX sha256;

    /* complete = salt_str + string */
    if (sprintf(salt_str, "%lu", salt) < 0)
        error_handler("compute_sha256 | sprintf");
    if (strcpy(complete, salt_str) == NULL)
        error_handler("compute_sha256 | strcpy");
    if (strcat(complete, string) == NULL)
        error_handler("compute_sha256 | strcat");

    /* compute sha256 of 'complete' */
    if (SHA256_Init(&sha256) == 0)
        error_handler("compute_sha256 | SHA256_Init");
    if (SHA256_Update(&sha256, complete, sizeof(complete)) == 0)
        error_handler("compute_sha256 | SHA256_Update");
    if (SHA256_Final(hash, &sha256) == 0)
        error_handler("compute_sha256 | SHA256_Final");
    for (i = 0; i < SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH; i++)
        if ((sprintf(temp + (i * 2), "%02x", hash[i])) < 0)
            error_handler("compute_sha256 | sprintf");

    temp[64] = 0;

    if (strcpy(sha, temp) == NULL)
        error_handler("compute_sha256 | strcpy");

    printf("SHA256 (sizeof_complete):\t%s\n", sha);
}

void compute_sha256_with_strlen_complete(const char *string, char *sha)
{
    int i;
    char temp[65];
    char complete[MAX_LENGTH];
    char salt_str[MAX_LENGTH];
    unsigned char hash[SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH];  
    SHA256_CTX sha256;

    /* complete = salt_str + string */
    if (sprintf(salt_str, "%lu", salt) < 0)
        error_handler("compute_sha256 | sprintf");
    if (strcpy(complete, salt_str) == NULL)
        error_handler("compute_sha256 | strcpy");
    if (strcat(complete, string) == NULL)
        error_handler("compute_sha256 | strcat");

    /* compute sha256 of 'complete' */
    if (SHA256_Init(&sha256) == 0)
        error_handler("compute_sha256 | SHA256_Init");
    if (SHA256_Update(&sha256, complete, strlen(complete)) == 0)
        error_handler("compute_sha256 | SHA256_Update");
    if (SHA256_Final(hash, &sha256) == 0)
        error_handler("compute_sha256 | SHA256_Final");
    for (i = 0; i < SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH; i++)
        if ((sprintf(temp + (i * 2), "%02x", hash[i])) < 0)
            error_handler("compute_sha256 | sprintf");

    temp[64] = 0;

    if (strcpy(sha, temp) == NULL)
        error_handler("compute_sha256 | strcpy");

    printf("SHA256 (strlen_complete):\t%s\n", sha);
}

// Normal ////////////////////////////////

void compute_sha256_with_sizeof_string(const char *string, char *sha)
{
    int i;
    char temp[65];
    char complete[MAX_LENGTH];
    char salt_str[MAX_LENGTH];
    unsigned char hash[SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH];  
    SHA256_CTX sha256;

    /* complete = salt_str + string */
    if (sprintf(salt_str, "%lu", salt) < 0)
        error_handler("compute_sha256 | sprintf");
    if (strcpy(complete, salt_str) == NULL)
        error_handler("compute_sha256 | strcpy");
    if (strcat(complete, string) == NULL)
        error_handler("compute_sha256 | strcat");

    /* compute sha256 of 'string' */
    if (SHA256_Init(&sha256) == 0)
        error_handler("compute_sha256 | SHA256_Init");
    if (SHA256_Update(&sha256, string, sizeof(string)) == 0)
        error_handler("compute_sha256 | SHA256_Update");
    if (SHA256_Final(hash, &sha256) == 0)
        error_handler("compute_sha256 | SHA256_Final");
    for (i = 0; i < SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH; i++)
        if ((sprintf(temp + (i * 2), "%02x", hash[i])) < 0)
            error_handler("compute_sha256 | sprintf");

    temp[64] = 0;

    if (strcpy(sha, temp) == NULL)
        error_handler("compute_sha256 | strcpy");

    printf("SHA256 (sizeof_string):\t\t%s\n", sha);
}

void compute_sha256_with_strlen_string(const char *string, char *sha)
{
    int i;
    char temp[65];
    char complete[MAX_LENGTH];
    char salt_str[MAX_LENGTH];
    unsigned char hash[SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH];  
    SHA256_CTX sha256;

    /* complete = salt_str + string */
    if (sprintf(salt_str, "%lu", salt) < 0)
        error_handler("compute_sha256 | sprintf");
    if (strcpy(complete, salt_str) == NULL)
        error_handler("compute_sha256 | strcpy");
    if (strcat(complete, string) == NULL)
        error_handler("compute_sha256 | strcat");

    /* compute sha256 of 'string' */
    if (SHA256_Init(&sha256) == 0)
        error_handler("compute_sha256 | SHA256_Init");
    if (SHA256_Update(&sha256, string, strlen(string)) == 0)
        error_handler("compute_sha256 | SHA256_Update");
    if (SHA256_Final(hash, &sha256) == 0)
        error_handler("compute_sha256 | SHA256_Final");
    for (i = 0; i < SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH; i++)
        if ((sprintf(temp + (i * 2), "%02x", hash[i])) < 0)
            error_handler("compute_sha256 | sprintf");

    temp[64] = 0;

    if (strcpy(sha, temp) == NULL)
        error_handler("compute_sha256 | strcpy");

    printf("SHA256 (strlen_string):\t\t%s\n", sha);
}

void match_password(const char *line)
{
    char hash[MAX_LENGTH];
    salt *= 13;

    compute_sha256_with_strlen_complete(line, hash);
    compute_sha256_with_sizeof_complete(line, hash);
    compute_sha256_with_strlen_string(line, hash);
    compute_sha256_with_sizeof_string(line, hash);
}

void read_password_from_stdin(void)
{
    char line[MAX_LENGTH];
    salt = 2000;

    printf("> ");

    if (fgets(line, MAX_LENGTH, stdin) == NULL)
        error_handler("read_password_from_stdin | fgets");
    if (line[strlen(line)-1] == '\n')
        line[strlen(line)-1] = '\0';

    match_password(line);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (argc != 1)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <no arguments>\n", argv[0]);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    while (!feof(stdin))
        read_password_from_stdin();

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sizeof(complete)` is always `MAX_LENGTH`, or 1024.  In `compute_sha256_with_sizeof_complete`, `complete` and `salt_str` are local variables, so are allocated on the stack and may have any contents when the function starts running, depending on the compiler.  I would guess that there are at least some nonzero values in `complete`, and `strcpy` and `strcat` won't replace those values unless the salt string, or what you read from `stdin`, is `MAX_LENGTH` characters long.  Therefore, you are getting the SHA-256 not only of the data you put in, but also of whatever random data is in `complete` when `compute_sha256_with_sizeof_complete` starts running.

This is also the reason the `sizeof_complete` output changes every time: the random data left in the stack, and therefore in `complete`, can be different each time the program runs.  To initialize it expressly, you could say `char complete[MAX_LENGTH] = {0};`, but you are better off to just not use `sizeof` in this situation :) .

Using `strlen`, by contrast, hashes only the string contents up to the terminating NULL character.  The `strcpy` and `strcat` fill in that part of the string as you expect, which is why you get the result you expect.  `strlen` is definitely the right choice here.  (And while you're coding, use `strncpy` and `strncat` instead of `strcpy` and `strcat` for [added protection against memory issues](https://buildsecurityin.us-cert.gov/articles/knowledge/coding-practices/strncpy-and-strncat).)

Answer (score 1):

Using `sizeof`, you compute sha on every octet of `complete` (*ie* on `MAX_LENGTH` octets) instead only on useful octets.

And `complete` is not initialized, so content can be anything, and different on each launch. Using `sprintf`, `strcat` and `strcpy` only initialize parts containing string, so end of array still uninitialized. To have every time same hash, initialize `complete`:

```
char complete[MAX_LENGTH] = { 0 };
```